# File read permissions for 'others' not working

Tags: linux, file-permissions, logfiles

I'm trying to give read permissions to lighttpd access logfiles to normal users which are on the same system.
The permissions are currently:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 211K Feb 28 11:27 /var/log/lighttpd/access.log`

So, if I understood correctly *others* have read permissions. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. If I try to read this file with an user account I get:

`/var/log/lighttpd/access.log: Permission denied`

I already tried to add the user to the group www-data which didn't work as well.
Any hints what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: is there anything like selinux running ?

Comment: @user1281385 Nope, the system is a simple Ubuntu 12.04. Selinux is not installed.

Comment: what does `lsattr /var/log/lighttpd/access.log` show

Comment: Output of `sudo lsattr /var/log/lighttpd/access.log` is `-------------e- /var/log/lighttpd/access.log`

Comment: Is the directory above accessible to your user? What are the permissions on `/var/log/lighthttpd`?

Comment: @Arsen7 it shouldnt matter for read only. Is the user in group adm ?

Comment: Yes, the user is in `adm`. Groups reveal: `adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare admin`. @Arsen7: The permissions on `/var/log/lighttpd` are www-data www-data

Comment: @user1281385 I'm not sure whether I understand properly, but I meant that if the user has no access to the directory containing the file (in this case: 'x' permission for 'others'), then he will still get the presented error.

Comment: @NewProggie `www-data` is the user/group. Please, check whether there are three `x` in the first column of the `ls -ld /var/log/lighthttpd`

Comment: @Arsen7: Well, yes, I've tried somewhat different before. I had given 655 permission to the file `/var/log/lighttpd/access.log`, but wasn't able to view the file. If I give 655 permissions to `/var/log/lighttpd` it is working. Thanks for your help. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access a file, the system needs the `execute` permission on all the directories containing the file.

In this case it was necessary to issue the `chmod o+x /var/log/lighthttps` command (after making sure that the user belongs to the "other" part of the permission set).

The "execute" permission *for a directory* allows you to enter it. The "read" permission for the directory allows you to see the names of the files inside. The interesting thing is that you can give the `x` permission alone, what means that anyone can access the files inside, but he needs to know its names.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have execute permission for the lighthttpd so the directory does not give the permission to access its containing file.

Use the command to set the execute permission to that directory.

```
chmod +x /var/log/lighthttpd
```